# How to build HoltWinters and Stepwise Autoregressive time series model with constant and linear trend in R package

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I am trying to build four time series models in R

1) HoltWinters with constant trend,

2) HoltWinters with linear trend,

3) Stepwise autoregressive with constant trend,

2) Stepwise autoregressive with linear trend

In SAS I can do this using PROC Forecast and specifying method and trend option.

Could you please help me in doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Try `? HoltWinters` to get help on the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1 and 2:

```
library(forecast)
fit1 <- ets(x, model="ANA", damped=FALSE)
fit2 <- ets(x, model="AAA", beta=0, damped=FALSE, lower=rep(0,4))
```

By default, `ets` does not allow constant components (such as a linear trend), but setting the lower limit to 0 allows it.

For 3 and 4, I am not sure what you mean by "stepwise autoregressive". Perhaps you mean a subset autoregression where the terms are chosen using a stepwise procedure. For that, see the FitAR package (http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i02/paper). However, I don't think it allows a deterministic trend.

Comment: Thanks Rob. This helped a lot.

Comment: Hi Rob, May be it sounds funny, but while upvoting it, the system is asking for 15 reputations. I am not sure how to get that for upvoting. Could you please help me doing that?